# Storing current URL then opening it later in Selenium IDE

Tags: url, variables, selenium-ide

the application I am testing generates a dynamic URL that I need to go back to later to perform further actions on.

I can store the URL using

```
storeLocation | url
```

However, I am not sure how I can later call that URL using the open command

I want something like:

```
open | {$url}
```

however, that does not fetch the stored location in SeleniumIDE.

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $ needs to be outside the curly braces, like so:

`open | ${url}`

See here: [Parsing URL for querystring values with Selenium IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375841/parsing-url-for-querystring-values-with-selenium-ide)